# Extract the drop down items of the button from jasmine test

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, jasmine

I have a angular component with html, .ts, and .scss file. The html file has a button (see below) and the button has 2 dropdown items. I am testing my html template using Karma and jasmine. I am trying to test and verify that the button has two dropdown items in it. I tried click() using

```
debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#header-theme-btn'));
        htmlElement = debugElement.nativeElement;
        htmlElement.click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
```

and then

```
const dropdownItems = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'));
```

but my dropdownItems is always null.

**Can anyone help me on how to extract the drop down items of the button from test?Or suggest better way to do this. Please and Thank you.**

**HTML snippet**

```html
 <div id="theme-btn" class="btn-group" dropdown placement="bottom right">
      <button id="header-theme-btn"
              dropdownToggle type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
        Theme
      </button>
      <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        <a id="dark-theme-menuitem"
           class="dropdown-item list-group-item"
           [class.active]="activeTheme === blueXTheme.Dark"
           (click)="setTheme(blueXTheme.Dark)">
          Dark
        </a>
        <a id="light-theme-menuitem"
           class="dropdown-item list-group-item"
           [class.active]="activeTheme === blueXTheme.Light"
           (click)="setTheme(blueXTheme.Light)">
          Light
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You selectors are not correct,  try `.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu-right` ( i think you forgot a . )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think my click() call works, because on the actual page I can only see the <ul> stuff after I click on the Theme button. The dropdownItems are always null